# Toggel between XAML an code in visual studio with Xamarin forms

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, xamarin.forms

I'm currently using visual studio with Xamarin forms. When I did XAML with WPF it was possible to toggle between xaml and c# pressing <kbd>F7</kbd>. Its also currently assigned but not working. Is anyone else having this issue with Visual Studio 2015?

Comment: From your comments below F7/Shift+F7 is for Xaml designer and Xaml Code not for Xaml and C# code behind.@RasmusChristensen

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about Visual Studio 2015, but in Visual Studio 2013 you can right-click the `class` reference in your XAML file for the page and click **Go To Declaration** which will take you to your code-behind file. You can also do the same from your code-behind file to get into the XAML file it is attached to.

So for example, if your `ContentPage` is called `WelcomePage`, then in your `WelcomePage`'s XAML file, you would right click the word `WelcomePage` below:

```
x:Class="YourNamespace.Pages.WelcomePage"
```

And in your code-behind you would right click `WelcomePage` below:

```
public partial class WelcomePage : ContentPage {
    ....
}
```

Maybe this could be a workaround for you if the VS 2015 feature is not working correctly.

Also if you have R# installed, you only need to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + click the `WelcomePage` text to move between the XAML and code-behind.

Comment: I'm looking for a non mouse option. And VS says F7 /Shift + F7 should toggle